# JavaScript for HTTP post XML with authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, cross-domain

I want to implement something like 
curl --digest -u username:password -d "mydata" http://example.com/push
with Javascript as a chrome plugin.
Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

      function setHeader(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', $.base64Encode('username:password'));
      }

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://example.com/push",
        data: "<Phone><Data>mydata</Data></Phone>",
        xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: setHeader,
        success: function (data,status,xhr){
          //do something
        }
      });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a cross domain POST with HTTP Basic Authentication.
Because of CORS, chrome browser instead of POST sends an OPTIONS message challenge for originate. 
If I changed url to same domain, it works. 
If I disabled authentication, it also works.
But I have to POST to the other domain, which is not under my control, that means I cannot use solutions like easyXDM. They also require HTTP Basic Authentication. I have been looking for solution for a week. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: If they don't support CORS (`OPTIONS`), there is nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password) //usage: Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#BasicAA